# Industrial Applications of Gekko

Tags: gekko

I'm an intern at an engineering consulting firm in Canada that's interested in looking at using Gekko for some industrial applications. My supervisor asked me to look into some of the places where the code has been used in industry for preliminary research.

I did find some industrial examples at:https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/APMonitorReferences. Just looking to see if anyone else has examples of instances where Gekko has been used in industry application-wise, and any roadblocks that were come across. I know specifics can't really be given for privacy and confidentiality reasons, but any information would be helpful.

Comment: Asking for off-site contact via email is unacceptable here. If the question can't be answered here, it's not appropriate to ask here. IMO, neither is the question itself, as it is not a specific question related to programming (code) or use of a programmers tool (IDE, compiler, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Claire, congrats on the internship. That is very good experience to have an internship where you apply theory to applications. When I did an internship at ExxonMobil during my graduate studies, it helped to give a unique perspective on the challenges and opportunities.

Here are a few things that I've come across:

1. Model development is typically only 20% of the effort. The other 80% is documentation, training, user interface, interface tags, and edge cases (start-up, shut-down, watchdog application).
2. Python is a very flexible environment. Supporting packages such as [pyModbus](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), [OPC-UA](https://python-opcua.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), or SQL ([How do you implement a Python Gekko application for real time systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57085640/how-do-you-implement-a-python-gekko-application-for-real-time-systems)) help to move data. Packages such as NumPy and Pandas help with data cleansing and pre-processing. There are other packages for making nice UIs and there is also an automatic GUI built in to Gekko. If `m.solve(GUI=True)`, the results of this solve are sent to the GUI. If the GUI is not open yet, the GUI object is created, the server is spawned and the browser client is launched.
3. Digitalization and data quality are a key pre-requisite for advanced control.
4. It is important to quantify benefits and have metrics that show the benefits of any application.
5. Gekko has functions for [chemical process first principles modeling](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chemical.html) and also [identification (see sysid, arx)](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_methods.html) / [empirical modeling methods](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/brain.html). It combines both into a common framework.

Here is [information on Gekko applications in industry](https://machinelearning.byu.edu/).

**Industries Applied**

- Cogeneration
- Drilling automation
- Severe slugging control
- Solar thermal energy production
- Solid oxide fuel cells
- Flow assurance
- Enhanced oil recovery
- Essential oil extraction
- Unmanned aerial vehicles
- Food and beverage
- Pulp and paper
- Polyethylene reactors
- Polypropylene reactors
- Butyl rubber production
- Polyalphaolefins
- Systems biology

**Solving Modes**

- Machine Learning
- Data reconciliation
- Real-time optimization
- Digital twin dynamic simulation
- Moving horizon estimation
- Model predictive control

**Solving Methods**

- Linear programming (LP)
- Quadratic programming (QP)
- Quadratically constrained quadratic program (QPQC)
- Nonlinear programming (NLP)
- Mixed integer linear programming (MILP)
- Mixed integer nonlinear programming (MINLP)

I recommend that you reach out to the industrial authors of papers to see if they can share additional insights. Gekko is installed about 9,000-10,000 times per month, according to [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/project/gekko/) so I imagine that there are other appplications that are not published. Here is some information from Google Analytics from May 27, 2019 to May 26, 2020 on visitors to APMonitor/Gekko content.

[image: Google Analytics]

Many of them are students but there are some cities in the top 100 that show up from cities that are primarily industrial or have a strong company presence from that city. Here is a map of user location for the past year.

[image: APMonitor visitors]